# Is there a way to use CTRL and SUPER key modifiers together in a key binding?

Tags: key-bindings, osx, modifier-key

I would like to be able to use CTRL and SUPER key modifiers together in a key binding. Since I'm on Mac OSX  I use Command key for SUPER modifier.

I tried this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s-i") 'move-line-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s-k") 'move-line-down)
```

but I get `<C-s-268632073> is undefined` message in the mini buffer when I press `C-s-i` combination.

Is there a way to use CTRL and SUPER key modifiers together in a key binding?

Comment: Works for me with 25.2.2 on Linux, at least to the extent that `C-x @ s C-i` runs `move-line-up`. What version of Emacs are you running? Do you get this message when you run `global-set-key` or when you press C-s-i? What happens when you press `C-x @ s C-i` ?

Comment: @Fólkvangr tried it, but I get `Invalid read syntax: "?"` when I try to `eval-buffer`

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I'm on GNU Emacs 26.3. I get message when I press C-s-i. I get `C-x @ Tab is undefined` in the mini buffer when i press `C-x @ s C-i`

Comment: Did you press `C-x @ s C-i`, not `C-x @ Tab`? With a sequence beginning with `C-x @ s`, you should get a message about a translation.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' OK this sequence works `C-x @ s C-i` but if I literally press `s` key, not super.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' When I do that I get `s-TAB` message in the mini buffer when I press `C-x @ s C-i` and `C-s-k` when I press `C-x @ s C-k`.

Comment: @Fólkvangr OK, I tried this. When I use the `C-x C-e` key sequence I can see `backward-word` message in the mini buffer, but when I press `Super+Ctrl+i` sequence I still get `<C-s-268632073> is undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just upgraded Emacs from version 26.3 to 27.1 and the keybinding works just fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "s-C-i") 'move-line-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-C-k") 'move-line-down)
```

Dunno whether that works (I don't have a `<super>` key. The key description `C-s` means Control + `s` (character s, not super key).

Be aware, too, that `C-i` is the same as `TAB`.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately, it doesn't resolve the problem.